# Is there any error in insert functon of link-list?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, data-structures

#### WORD_LIST.H

I just want to create a link list ,i get the data from file line by line and store in link list but in the end of list i am calling display function so it's not printing the words but printing a single word **CNAA** again and again

```
 struct word_node {
      struct word_node * next;
      const char * word;
    };
    struct word_list {
      struct word_node * head;
      long num_words;
    };

    void reading_words(const char * filename);
    void insert(struct word_list *,const char*);
    void display(struct word_list *p);
```

#### WORD_LIST.C

```
 void reading_words(const char * filename){
      struct word_list *p ;
      FILE* file = fopen(filename,"r");
      char *line = NULL;
      size_t len = 0;
      ssize_t read;
      p = (struct word_list*)malloc(sizeof(struct word_list));
      p->head  =NULL;
      p->num_words =0;
      while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) {
        line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
        p->num_words++;
        insert(p,line);
       }
      printf("Size : %ld\n",p->num_words);
      display(p);
      return ;
    }
    void insert(struct word_list *p,const char* word){
      struct word_node *test ;
      test = (struct word_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct word_node));
      if(test == NULL){
        printf("Out of Memory!");
       }
      else{
        test->word = word;
        if(p->head == NULL){
           p->head = test
           p->head->next = NULL;
          }
        else{
           test->next = p->head;
           p->head = test;
          }
       }
    }
    void display(struct word_list *p){
      struct word_node *temp;
      temp = p->head;
      while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%s\n",temp->word);
        temp=temp->next;
       }
    }
```

According to Word file the words are
**GEEK
TOTE
ORVIE
YELD
MTA
ACOP
CIAO
DANCE
BSRT
CNAA**

But after insert function it is printing only **CNAA** 10 times

Answer (score 0):

When you insert words, you are calling

```
insert(p,line);
```

and pass local variable line (pointer to char) as an argument. Later in the insert function you have

```
test->word = word;
```

this is just making a copy of the pointer, so `test->word` will point to the same address as local variable `line` in the `reading_words` function. Because of that, each element of the list points to the same address.
Instead, you should use `strcpy` to copy the string, but before that, you have to allocate memory for the string (and free it somewhere later). Something like:

```
test->word = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
strcpy(test-word,word);
```

Comment: You need strlen(word)+1, to account for the end-of-string nul (`\0`), though.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to update `reading_words` function as follows:

```c
...
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) {
    line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
    p->num_words++;
    insert(p,line);
    line = NULL;
    len = 0;
}
...
```

By the documentation of `getline(3)` ([link](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)):

> If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then
> getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others, you are inserting the same pointer to each word, and getline() only happens to change the contents of the buffer that pointer points to.

I would recommend using a C99 flexible array member instead of a pointer:

```c
struct word {
    struct word *next;
    char         word[];
};

struct word *new_word(const char *);
void         insert_word(struct word **, struct word *);

struct word *read_words(FILE *);
void         free_words(struct word *);
void         show_words(struct word *, FILE *);
```

The `new_word()` function creates a new `struct word` from a given string, by *copying* the data to the new dynamically allocated structure:

```c
struct word *new_word(const char *src)
{
    const size_t  srclen = (src) ? strlen(src) : 0;
    struct word  *w;

    w = malloc(sizeof (struct word) + srclen + 1);
    if (!w) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    w->next = NULL;

    if (srclen > 0)
        memcpy(w->word, src, srclen);

    w->word[srclen] = '\0';

    return w;
}
```

The above works (creating an empty word) even when `src == NULL`.  Because `strlen(NULL)` is not safe, we use the `(expression) ? (if-true) : (if-false)` *ternary expression* to calculate the length of the data.  Similarly, we don't want to use `memcpy()` to copy the data if there is no data.

The other new function, `free_words()`, can be used to free a whole list of words, taking the pointer to the first word in the list:

```c
void free_words(struct word *list)
{
    while (list) {
        struct word *curr = list;

        list = list->next;

        /* Poison the word, so that if we accidentally
           use a word after it has been freed, we'll
           surely notice.  This is purely a measure to
           help with debugging programming bugs. */
        curr->next = NULL;
        curr->word[0] = '\0';

        /* Free this word. */
        free(curr);
    }
}
```

Because `insert_word()` now takes a pointer to a pointer (a pointer to the list variable), and a pointer to the structure to be inserted, it becomes trivial:

```c
void insert_word(struct word **listptr, struct word *w)
{
    /* Only do this if neither pointer is NULL. */
   if (listptr && w) {
       w->next = *listptr;
       *listptr = w;
   }
}
```

We can even implement `insert_words()`, which inserts a list in front of another list:

```c
void insert_words(struct word **list, struct word *first)
{
    if (list && first) {
        struct word *last = first;

        /* Find last word in first-list */
        while (last->next)
            last = last->next;

        last->next = *list;
        *list = first;
    }
}
```

The `show_words()` is almost unchanged, except that I prefer it takes the stream it should print to as a second parameter.  Normally, it will just be `stdout`.

```c
void show_words(struct word *list, FILE *out)
{
    if (list && out) {
        while (list) {
            fputs(list->word, out);
            fputs("\n", out);
            list = list->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that because C passes parameters by value, modifying the `list` variable is only visible within the function itself.  Whatever variable the caller uses to pass to `show_words()` is not modified, even though we modify `list` in `show_words()`.

This leaves `read_words()`.  Again, I prefer passing the stream handle instead of the file name to the function.  This way you can read input from standard input too, by just passing `stdin`.  The function returns the list of words read, *in reverse order*, because we prepend each word we read to the beginning of the list.

```c
struct word *read_words(FILE *in)
{
    struct word *list = NULL;
    struct word *curr;
    char        *line = NULL;
    size_t       size = 0;
    ssize_t      len;

    if (!in)
        return NULL;

    while (1) {
        len = getline(&line, &size, in);
        if (len == -1)
            break;

        unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)line;
        unsigned char *end = (unsigned char *)line + len;

        /* Skip leading whitespace (including newline). */
        while (ptr < end && isspace(*ptr))
            ptr++;

        /* Trim trailing whitespace (including newline). */
        while (end > ptr && isspace(end[-1]))
            end--;
        *end = '\0';

        /* Create the word structure. */
        curr = new_word(ptr);

        /* Prepend to the list. */
        insert_word(&list, curr);
    }

    /* Line buffer is no longer needed.  Note, free(NULL) is safe to do. */
    free(line);

    return list;
}
```

The reason for `unsigned char *ptr` and `unsigned char *end` is that `isspace()` takes the character code *cast to unsigned char*.  If we used just `char *`, we'd have to use `isspace((unsigned char)(*ptr))` and `isspace((unsigned char)(end[-1]))` for isspace() to work correctly in all cases.

You should also include `<locale.h>` and `<ctype.h>`, and in the beginning of your `main()`, tell the C library to use the current locale for the user running the program, via

```c
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Based on the character set used (it is part of the locale), `isspace()` may consider different codes as spaces.  In particular, if one uses ISO Latin 1, ISO Latin 15, or Windows-1252 (8-bit Western European), code 160 (non-breaking space) is also considered a space.  (If you use such a locale in Linux, you usually type it via AltGr+Space.)
It's only a small thing to add, and makes your code work as expected by the user in many different situations.

If you want the word list in the original file order, then you'll need to reverse it.  Fortunately, that is very easy to do:

```c
struct word *reverse_word_order(struct word *list)
{
    struct word *newlist = NULL;

    while (list) {
        struct word *curr = list;

        /* Advance original list pointer */
        list = list->next;

        /* Prepend word to newlist */
        curr->next = newlist;
        newlist = curr;
    }

    return newlist;
}
```